# How to create a dummy (0 Byte) HDFS file in Pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to find a python utility which lets me create a dummy file on HDFS dynamically without touching local file system.

Experts, i have a simple requirement where i need to create a dummy (0 byte) file in HDFS in Pyspark code. Basically i am checking if x.lock (0 byte) file exists on HDFS and if it does, it means that i need to wait until other process (which created it) is complete and deletes it. If it doesn't exists, My job will create it and proceed with execution and at the end, it will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following native pythonhdfs connector: https://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/

Try the following solutions (libhdfs or libhdfs3):

```py
from pyarrow import HdfsClient
# Using libhdfs
hdfs = HdfsClient(host, port, username, driver='libhdfs') 
# Using libhdfs3
hdfs_alt = HdfsClient(host, port, username, driver='libhdfs3')
path = '/user/dummy.txt'
with hdfs.open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write("")
```